# How set the correct version of play-services in Ionic Pro

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-plugins

In the project replacement in the platform / android / projet.properties the following parameters

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+`

`cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+`

How do I replace the same in the project or configuration and then charge it to the ionic pro and build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the next plugin: cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release

1. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
2. ionic cordova platform remove android
3. ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0

this resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had slightly different issue which wasn't solved using cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.

We were using [cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) which was adding

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11+
```

which was in conflict with [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/).  (I think the difference with OP being **-location** specified at the end)

Couldn't find a gradle for the play-services-location so the only way to fix was to re-install the plugin with the --GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION specified, eg...

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation --variable GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=11.6.2
```

Am fairly new to cordova development, but I get the impression that most (all?) plugins allow you to specify this variable and you should use it just as a matter of course to resolve these conflicts before they happen.